# Grammatical error? or intentional colloquialism?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, grammatical-correction

> Got a question that you can’t ask on public Stack Overflow? Learn more about sharing private information with Stack Overflow for Teams.

There's a grammatical error in this phrase that appears in a Stack Overflow internal ad. It should read

> Have a question…?

Chances are you didn't *get* a question [from someone/somewhere] that you can't ask publicly; you have it because you formed it yourself.

I realize people do say this a lot, so it would be understandable if it was intentionally "incorrect" to sound more informal and relatable to what the SO team perceives as their audience. I just want to raise the question in case it was unintentional.

Comment: That sounds like perfectly normal colloquial English to me.

Comment: It's perfectly grammatical anyway. The verb "get" is allowed to be used without specifying a source - it just means "to come to possess". You don't have to have gotten something *from* somewhere. https://www.dictionary.com/browse/get

Comment: There’s a big difference between “I have got” and just “got”. It isn’t true that all uses of “got” are incorrect. It is, however, true that this usage is. It is extremely colloquial, like “Got milk?” in the ad. It is also wrong. It makes no sense. English doesn’t form questions this way. You can’t ask, “Make bread?” or “Wrote book?”. Those aren’t complete sentences. On the other hand, taking off my prescriptivist hat, I could see an argument for intentionally using the highly colloquial form for an emphasis on simplicity.

Comment: Then why is the suggested "Have a question?" any more "grammatical" than "Got a question?"? The only difference is whether we elide an initial "Do you" or "Have you".

Comment: Indeed it *is* bad grammar. Just like we say "that question reek**s**" but "many question**s** reek", then the correct form here is "**Gots** a question..." (^_^)

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/808

Comment: @BrockAdams or more formally, "*Youse guys* gots a question.." :P

Comment: @CodyGray The use of informal but widely recognized language here is probably an attempt to create an atmosphere of familiarity. Someone probably thought it seemed "welcoming." Formally correct language often caries an impersonal tone and is commonly (although not really fairly) associated with arrogance and dismissal. In this case, it ironically is probably confusing to non-native speakers, which would probably be regarded as "unwelcoming" to them by the very same people who thought it was a good idea.

Comment: It is colloquial and so it should not be written. We should not encourge bad English. What next, lenient speling ? i think not.

Comment: It is actually ambiguous now that you have brought it up.

Comment: I'm very sure a lot of deliberation went into the wording of that message. And in addition to the great point that @Blorgbeard makes, I can't really find anything ambiguous or abnormal about the wording (coming from a non-native speaker that mainly learned English from exposure to it). Whether to follow the rules regarding formal writing is SO's decision, and they're quite clearly not going for a formal tone here.

Comment: @TaW I assume that was sarcastic given the spelling and grammar of your comment.. you never know on the internet though.

Comment: @Blorgbeard the formal is quickly becoming "Y'all", thankfully. "Youse guys" for a second-person plural pronoun is laughable, naturally!

Comment: Colloquial English is rarely taught outside of English-native-language countries. So foreigners struggle while guessing the meaning. That's pretty common that people think the rest of the world is about two km around. This is a US site, isn't it? So, I better use miles instead of km... and `gotta`, `wanna` and so on, buddies.

Comment: Yes, it’s definitely an acceptable colloquialism. It’s just a different tone than I’m used to seeing on SO and professional websites in general.

Comment: Surely both of the given options by the OP are invalid? They should be `Have you got a question...?` or `Do you have a question...?`, at least in written English (see also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100459/do-you-have-vs-have-you-got)

Comment: @CodyGray There’s a difference between informal and incorrect. This usage is perfectly grammatical as a colloquialism, and this is clearly the intended usage. It isn’t formal, and that’s the point. Whether it’s appropriate here is purely a question of style, not of correctness.

Comment: `[Have you] got a question?` and `[Do you] have a question?` are both fine, but I'd expect to hear the first.

Comment: @Dan Or ***Do you have got** a question?*

Comment: @CodyGray, looks like you live in the U.S. You were never asked "Got a quarter?" as you walked down the street?

Comment: Yes, I live in the US. I can't recall ever being asked for a quarter, though. I think the minimum expected donation these days is a dollar. :-) Either way, I'm not sure what your point is. I granted in my original comment that constructions like "Got a quarter?" and "Got milk?" do exist as extreme colloquialisms, but are grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Consensus seems to be that it’s fine for SO to be using this informal colloquialism. Works for me!