# "Lifeboat" blog post grammatical error

Tags: bug, blog, grammatical-correction

Emboldened by [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386836/where-to-report-stackoverflow-internal-ad-grammatical-error?cb=1#comment709102_386836), I would like to report a bug on 
[the Lifeboat-announcement blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/).  I reported it as a comment, but the comment apparently didn't survive moderation :) .

Would someone please change the post title?

```
From:  Adios to Unfriendly Badges: Ahoy, Lifejacket and Lifeboat
To:    Adios to Unfriendly Badges; Ahoy, Lifejacket and Lifeboat
                                 ^ semicolon instead of colon
```

or, if you prefer,

```
To:    Adios to Unfriendly Badges!  Ahoy, Lifejacket and Lifeboat!
```

Every time I read the current title, the meaning I perceive is "Good-bye to the unfriendly badges in the following list: the Ahoy badge, the Lifejacket badge, and the Lifeboat badge."  I submit that, with a semicolon or exclamation mark, "ahoy" is clearly a verb rather than the first element of a list.

Thank you for considering this request!

Comment: I’m glad to see that I’ve been influential! I love a good grammar nitpick. So here’s one for free: your misreading of the current title isn’t a result of a grammatical error. The title is fine as written. Your misreading is actually grammatically incorrect, as it assumes that the clause following the colon is a list of three items. It cannot be, however, because there is only one comma. This makes me [a bit apprehensive about attending your next party](http://i.imgur.com/rTEJkwH.jpg).

Comment: Maybe an "NSFW" warning would be appropriate there, @CodyGray. Though, perhaps [I should know better than to click an imgur link while at work](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LxFEG.jpg).

Comment: Just a nitpick, but the "...one for free: your misreading" should be "...one for free:  Your misreading...", correct?  :P

Comment: @Paul No, I don’t believe so. Whether to capitalize the phrase after a colon is more a style thing than a grammar thing, but I learned not to do it, and that’s consistent with most style guides that I’ve seen since. Grammatically, it’s no different than capitalizing after a semicolon or a coordinating conjunction.

Comment: @PaulBeverage aha! No, the word following a colon should not be capitalized.

Comment: Depends on where you're from, I guess.  In the US, and from many college paper corrections, it is almost always capitalized because of how it is used. But hey, to each their own ;)  Mine is based on the same silly rules as what created the APA style:  https://apastyle.apa.org/learn/faqs/colon-use

Comment: The comma after "Ahoy" is confusing too.

Comment: @CodyGray, your linked picture was intended to describe the difference between the Oxford comma and missing Oxford comma. But de facto it describes the difference between the colon and the comma. The upper half is "we invited the strippers⁣**,** jfk(,) and stalin", the lower half is "we invited the strippers⁣**:** jfk(,) and stalin". (At least, that's how that punctuation would be understood by non-native speakers.)

Comment: I confused `Ahoy, Lifejacket and Lifeboat` for a list of 3 badges.

Answer (score -4):

I don't see this as a grammatical error. From [grammarbook.com](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/colons.asp):

> A colon instead of a semicolon may be used between independent clauses
>   **when the second sentence explains, illustrates, paraphrases, or
>   expands on the first sentence.**

Emphasis, mine. Keep in mind that there are *not* independent clauses. The purpose of the blog post is to introduce the new badges. I think the colon is fine here because the first part of the sentence "Adios to Unfriendly Badges" is a segue into the introduction of the new badges.

The consensus on [english.stackexchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1183) also seems to say the same thing:

> Use a semi-colon to connect two related independent clauses.

and,

> Use a colon to separate equal things (like an '=' sign).

The removal of the old badges and the introduction of the new ones are not independent events.

Comment: While I agree that the current title is grammatically correct, your reasoning isn’t quite right, either. “Independent” doesn’t mean “unrelated” in these definitions. It’s a technical grammatical term describing a complete clause—one with a subject and a verb that could be a complete, standalone sentence. A semicolon would work here, but so does a colon.

Comment: @CodyGray I used "not independent" to mean that there is a cause-effect relationship between the two events in the sentence the colon separates. But you are correct :)

Comment: **Use a semi-colon to connect two related independent clauses** That's exactly what the title contains. A semicolon is the most appropriate punctuation mark here.

Comment: However it's long been a matter of style to [mis-]use the colon in article headlines like this. If it weren't for the resulting confusion/ambiguity in this particular case I'd say leave it as it is. And that's me, the world's _biggest_ proponent of semicolon education!